# Place element inside other element using absolute. Elements are siblings

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I am trying to place an element, "inner", flush against the upper right hand corner of another div, "outer", using absolute positioning. The "inner" element is not a child of "outer". I therefore need to look up the positioning of "outer" using js and use that.

However, it's not coming out quite right:

EDIT: it's not possible for me to reset the margin/padding/relative of the body div. There are other elements inside body.

http://jsfiddle.net/BZBSF/1/

```
#wrapper{background:red;
         width:100px;
         height:100px;}

#inner{
    position:absolute;
    background:green;
    width:50px;
    height:100px;
    margin:0;padding:0;
}

#body{position:relative;}

<div id = "body">
    <div id = "wrapper"></div>
    <div id = "inner"></div>    
</div>

var rect = document.getElementById("wrapper").getBoundingClientRect();

$("#inner").css({ 'top': String($(window).scrollTop()+rect.top)+"px" });

width_inner = $("#inner").width();

$("#inner").css({ 'left': String($(window).scrollLeft()+rect.right-width_inner)+"px" });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set margin and padding on the body element.

```
body{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;    
}
```

> [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/BZBSF/7/)

Or if there is no specific reason for body: relative; remove that.

> [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/BZBSF/9/)

The second one is recommended.

Comment: I cannot change the padding/margin of body. However, I can add these amounts to the positioning of "inner" now that I understand what is causing the offset. I worried that it was something browser specific.

Comment: @user984003 You could also set a negative margin-top on the inner element. Choose what works best for you.

Answer (score 2):

Is this what you want?

```
var rect = $('#wrapper');

$("#inner").css({ 'top': rect.position().top+"px" });

$("#inner").css({ 'left': (rect.position().left + rect.width() - $('#inner').width())+"px" });
```

http://jsfiddle.net/araSp/2/

And if you need to worry about padding/borders, you can use:

[.innerWidth()](http://api.jquery.com/innerWidth/)

[.outerWidth()](http://api.jquery.com/outerWidth/)

Answer (score 1):

Just do a quick reset on the top:

```
* {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Y9YWV/)

Note: This is a quick reset. You might want to use other reset stylesheets out there.

Answer (score 1):

You should remove the position relative at the body tag.

```
 $(document).ready(function() {

    $('#inner').css({
        'position': 'absolute',
        'top': $('#wrapper').offset().top,
        'left': $('#wrapper').offset().left + $('#wrapper').width() - $('#inner').width()
    });

});
```

DEMO:

http://jsfiddle.net/4uSeV/

Comment: By using offset() rather than position(), this will break if the containing element is moved around the page.